# How should I store and compare 4 values for several instances of the same object type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working in Objective-C/Cocoa and I have an object type `Tile`. Each has a signature that can be represented as 4 different integer values. If I output a few these values as a string, with `-`es separating the values, it looks like this example:

```
signature: 4-4-3-3
signature: 4-3-3-3
signature: 0-0-0-1
signature: 0-0-1-1
signature: 0-0-1-0
signature: 1-1-1-2
signature: 1-1-2-2
signature: 1-1-2-1
signature: 3-3-3-1
signature: 3-3-1-1
signature: 3-3-1-3
signature: 4-4-4-3
signature: 4-4-3-3
```

I'm currently storing each of the values as an `unsigned short`. There never will be negative values and the maximum value is very unlikely to be above 15 or so. Zero is a valid value. There is no 'nil' value.

I would like to be able to call:

`[myTile signature]` to retrieve the value.

`[myTile matches:otherTile]` to return a `BOOL` indicating whether the signatures match.

What is the most efficient way to store this "signature" and compare it to the signatures of the other `Tile` instances? It seems like string comparisons would be slow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I'd use the commonly used methods names for these tasks: [`description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-SW7) and [`isEqual*:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCECDG).

Concerning your question, I think the best way is the simpler:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToTile:(Tile)tile
{
    return self.value1 == tile.value1 &&
           self.value2 == tile.value2 &&
           self.value3 == tile.value3 &&
           self.value4 == tile.value4;
}
```

Another possibility could be to implement [`hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGFFCH).

EDIT: I wouldn't worry too much about performance if I were you.

- Because 8 comparisons are fast. I mean *really* fast. If you were to put together a little benchmark, you would find that each comparison take ~`1.5E-8s` to run. This doesn't talk to me much, but lets just say you could make 10,000,000 of these comparisons under 100ms if my math is right.
- Because if one day you find your sofware slow, then it will be time to investigate the origin of this slowness (and I doubt it will come from this method), but remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).
- Because it took you 12 seconds to implement it, and it would probably take a bit more to think of a working `hash` function. Don't over-think it. See my second point.
- Because, if you need one day to optimize this function (if you are doing it now, re-read my second point), Cocoa have a couple handy tools to make your software doing such a dumb and repetitive task parallel. Without scratching your head to make it faster on only one of your (ever growing number of) cores.

Comment: Would one of these approaches have better performance than the other? I probably will need to iterate through a large number of these objects, performing comparisons, and do it quickly.

Comment: See my edit. tl;dr: don't worry about it, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Note: if you implement `isEqualToTile:` you should also implement `isEqual:` (takes an `NSObject`, check it's a `Tile`, return `NO` if not, otherwise return `isEqualToTile:`) *and* `hash`. If you don't do this parts of the framework, e.g. collections, will break if you use them with tiles.